# jquery slideup, slidedown, slidetoggle transitions - how to deactivate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slide

I have got the following problem:

I'm using a jquery script for a foldable menu. I would like to deactivate the transitions of the unfolding menu items, i.e. instead of sliding up/down, the UL of the submenu instantly appears or disappears.

I'm a beginner in jquery/js, so my question is:

Is there an easy way to change the script so that there are no transitions?

Comment: one method is by not assigning any transition and second method is by posting what you have tried..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $.fx.off that disables or enables the animations within jquery.
Example : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.off/

Comment: Great! Thanks a alot, I just added jQuery.fx.off = true; to the top of the function and there are no more transitions.